# c++: derived class implements virtual member function of base class, a second derived class not

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Shape
{
    public:
      Shape() {};
      virtual void fun1();

};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
   Rectangle(int width) {width=width;}
   double width;
};
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
   Circle(int radius) {radius=radius;}
   double radius;
   void fun1() {...} override;
};
```

//execute this code during runtime
std::shared_ptr ptr = std::make_shared(width);

This MWE shows that the derived class Rectangle does not implement the function fun1(), but the derived class Circle does.
What is a proper design to implement this?

Comment: fun1 isn't pure virtual. Also, please fix your code here, lots of typos (e.g. puclic instead of public).

Comment: Do you want to force implementing an abstract function in the derived class? Your ask is unclear.

Comment: @kiner_shah No, depending on the derived class, the function fun1() should be implemented or not. Because some of the derived classes do not need the function fun1().

Comment: Then, I think a good design will be to not have `virtual void fun1()` in `Shape` class at all. Instead where you need `fun1` just declare it there.

Comment: Yes, this came also to my mind (after I posted the question). Feel free to write this as an answer.

Comment: If *some* shapes can have `fun1`, but others cannot, you could have an intermediate class `FunShape` that derives from `Shape` and is the base class for those that can do fun.

Answer (score 0):

- in 9th line public spelling is wrong.
  -in class rectangle you first write double width;
  than function inside function write this.width=width;
  because two width name create confusion,similar in radious.

Comment: `this.width` would be a compiler error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void fun1() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(const double width) 
        : width{width}
    {}

    void fun1() override 
    {}

private:
   double width;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(const double radius)
        : radius{radius}
    {}

    void fun1() override 
    {}

private:
    double radius;    
};
```

Comment: I think this will throw an error because there is no implementation of fun1() in Rectangle.

Comment: you're right, implementation fixed